# Using prepareForSegue in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue

I'm trying to create a Segue when tapping on a UIView that causes a segue to a new view controller that holds the UIView that was tapped on. Basically taking a UIView that was only half the screen and making it the size of the whole screen.

I think I should use prepareForSegue to pass the UIView I tapped on to the new view controller, rather than create a new view, but I'm not sure if prepareForSegue should be autogenerated, and where it should be. I linked the tap gesture to a "Show" segue that opens the new view controller. I thought that prepareForSegue was auto-generated in Objective-C, so I'm not sure if I should be using it or not.

Another thought is that it could be in the tap gesture's action function, but I'm not sure if this is better or worse than prepareForSegue. The problem I see with that is there is no way to get a reference to the new view controller I'm moving to.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "autogenerated". You have to implement prepareForSegue yourself, but it is called by the system when the segue is initiated (you don't call it yourself). Be aware that if you're going to pass the view itself, you need to remove it from its superview first -- it can't be in 2 view controller at the same time.

Comment: By autogenerated I meant that it would be in the view controller code automatically (the method signature), but I'd have to implement it myself. I'm not sure if it applies here, however, because I don't know if I should use prepareForSegue or the UITapGestureRecognizer action to switch controllers.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of comments about what you stated...

> I think I should use prepareForSegue to pass the UIView I tapped on to
>   the new view controller, rather than create a new view...

You do not pass the UIView to the new view controller. You pass the UIImage that you want displayed to the new view controller.

> I linked the tap gesture to a "Show" segue that opens the new view controller.

That's a good start, also make sure that the UIImageView that you have attached the gesture to has its "User Interaction Enabled" flag set to true in the storyboard (I forget this one all the time.)

You have to write the prepare for segue yourself. You want to put the prepare for segue method into the origination view controller...

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected UIImage to the new view controller.
}
```

Comment: What I had meant was I expected the prepareForSegue method signature to be autogenerated. Also, I want the UIView to be able to be drawn on after the segue happens (but not before). Will a UIImage allow this? It sounds to me like a UIImage won't be modifiable.

Another option is that I have a different UIView generated for the new view controller that will then be able to be drawn on after the segue.

Comment: I was thinking you were displaying an image... Regardless, whatever data you are displaying in the UIView needs to be passed to the new view controller. You *don't* pass the UIView itself.

Answer (score 0):

An option may be to subclass UIStoryboardSegue and use that as your Custom segue. That way, you can get a handle on the fromVC and toVC, plus any views within them, for controlling how your segue looks and works.

Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomSegues/CreatingCustomSegues.html

Small example I found: http://www.albertopasca.it/whiletrue/2013/10/objectivec-uistoryboard-custom-transition/